# How does one hide content from a user until a stylesheet is loaded and executed?

Tags: jquery, css, events, jquery-events, onload

I'm using a jQuery plugin for sliding panes of content.  For about 400ms all the page elements flashes up (text, images, etc.) on top of themselves making for a messy garbled jumble... a brouhaha you could say.

Then the stylesheet comes along and sorts it all out.  But for the sake of professionalism and perfectionism I'd like to hide all the content until the stylesheet has loaded.

`$(document).ready` is inappropriate because boom... that's my problem.  `onload()` doesn't work either because then all content is hidden until the page completely renders (images...4, 5, 6 seconds...zzzzzzzz....)

So does anyone know what the options are?  (And would it be possible to play Girl From Ipanema midi during page load? :p)

Comment: What was `$(document).ready(function(){});`'s problem? Couldn't you hide your slideshow by default and in your ready function toggle it back on?

Comment: Maḥmūd! Somehow my first question on Stack was a complete bust.  Of course that's the answer!...ooops.  You're like the Hodja bringing me insight with your simple question.  Too bad I can't select a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have the stylesheet hide specific elements as `display: none` until they are needed.

However, if you do this directly in the stylesheet you've got accessibility problems, as on a browser without JavaScript available the content will not appear at all. A way around this is to key the hiddenness on a variable that is set from JavaScript before any of the deferrable elements are loaded, for example as a class on `<body>`:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.withjs .deferred { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('body').addClass('withjs');

        $(document).ready(function() {
            // set up slideyness
        });
    </script>

    <p>Content that loads normally...</p>

    <div id="slideything" class="deferred">
        content
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello!  This looks like the best of both worlds!  But, it sent me back into my old problem: having a bunch of layers of content on top of each other.  I don't know why.  I copied your code almost exactly.  Does the inline code load different way than as is presented in the document?

Comment: Can you put an example up (eg. pastebin et al)? Anything with class `deferred` should not be displayed at all on JS-enabled browsers; you can then set up the positioning and hidden/shownness of the deferred elements at document ready time. If you are just testing this on your local filesystem, be aware that IE turns JavaScript off by default.

Comment: perfect! got it to work.  thanks bobince! for your have-your-cake-and-eat-it-too solution.

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility-wise, you should not assume your stylesheets are actually being used by the client. Your content should be accessible without the stylesheet, and stylesheet should only enhance the presentation - that's [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

If accessibility matters less, you can hide the entire page (or at least the brouhaha) with `display: none` in the wrapper div or body.

Comment: Heyo Max!  Thanks for the article on Progressive Enhancement.  For now I'm going with display:hidden but I'll make it a near-future project to degrade gracefully with some cold Soviet cybernetics style text based website.  You answered my question with display: none.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to hide content that's going to be processed by JavaScript. You just need to generate the content itself with JavaScript or set its style to `display: none`.

The problems is accessibility. You normally want the content to be available for tools that do not support all the advanced features, including old browsers, search engines, mobiles phones, screen readers... That's what prevents you from doing what I mentioned in the first paragraph.

My advice is to alter your CSS so the content looks good even with JavaScript disabled.

(As for your latest requirement, you can use the [jQuery.ipanema-girl.js plugin](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DoHg5SJYRHA0&ei=Z3EoTKefOZWTjAfyjdx2&usg=AFQjCNEcy3X8QxEz3ZqmxAznmt4YfNijBQ&sig2=SrH0ofN9HEWj6WZF0sZx0g).)

Comment: Dude! I got RickRoll'd!  Alvaro, great advice!  Turns out that 
"display:hidden" isn't a thing.  Either "display:none" or "visibility:hidden."  But for all the other good advice I would of totally voted you up one if I had 15 reputation pts.  F! Who doesn't have 15 reputation points?!!

Comment: I fixed the CSS, thanks for pointing it out. And welcome to Stack Overflow. You get 15pt easily if you just come back ;-)